# e.range.getA1Notation() unable to track changes caused by formula update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I modified a script provided from this blog

[How to have your spreadsheet automatically send out an email when a cell value changes](http://blog.factivate.com/spreadsheet-automatically-send-email-cell-value-changes/)

After some debugging an modifications, I can send emails by manually entering a value at position C7. That is, according to script, if the value is greater than 100, it will send a email to me. That only happens if I type the number manually into the cell.

The problem is, if the value is generated by a formula, then it doesn't work. (Say cell C7 is a formula=C4*C5 where the product value is >100)

After some trial-and-error, I think it is the code in the edit detection part causing the problem.

```
var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation(); 
if(rangeEdit == "C7")
```

Since cell C7 is a formula, the formula itself doesn't change, what is changing is the values from formula calculations. So it may not think I have edited the cell.

How should I modify the script, so that the script also send email **when value of C7 produced by a formula is greater than 100**?

For reference, here is the code that I am using.

```
function checkValue(e)
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("C7").getValue();
var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();
if(rangeEdit == "C7")
{
if(valueToCheck >100)
{
MailApp.sendEmail("h********@gmail.com", "Campaign Balance", "Balance is currently at: " + valueToCheck+ ".");
}
}
}
```

Comment: So based on your example, C7 = C4*C5, who/what changes the value of c4 and c5? If it is modified by a user, you can just check to see if the value of C7 changes with each edit. Basically remove this if block `if(rangeEdit == "C7")`

Comment: C4 and C5 itself are some if-condition flags, and are changed by googlefinance, updated per minute. For example, if this stock rise, then C4=11, else 0, if stock is not blacklisted, then C5=11, else 0. This code is intended to block email submission every time the spreadsheet gets updated. Without this code I will be bombarded with emails every time the conditions are met. (However, I only need to be notified once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid repeated notifications due to edits in other places, send an email only when the value you are tracking is different from the previous one. Store the previous value in script properties.

```
function checkValue(e) {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("C7").getValue();
  var oldValue = sp.getProperty("C7") || 0;
  if (valueToCheck > 100 && valueToCheck != oldValue) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("***v@gmail.com", "Campaign Balance", "Balance is currently at: " + valueToCheck+ ".");
    sp.setProperty("C7", valueToCheck);
  }
}
```

Here the email is sent only when valueToCheck differs from the stored value. If this happens, the stored value is updated by `setProperty`.

Comment: I believe this script is what I need, many thanks! Regarding to google sheet API not working for google finance functions, I will have to test a few days later.

Comment: It works like a charm when I removed the on edit (e) thing and change the trigger to time driven per minute, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

onEdit(e) Trigger(Both simple and Installable) will not trigger unless a human explicitly edits the file. In your case, Your seem to be getting value from an external source (specifically, Google finance data).

> [Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling FormResponse.submit() to submit a new form response does not cause the form's submit trigger to run.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

> [Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit)

Also, for Google finance data,

> [Historical data cannot be downloaded or accessed via the Sheets API or Apps Script.  If you attempt to do so, you will see a #N/A error in place of the values in the corresponding cells of your spreadsheet.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)

#### Notes:

Having said that,

- In cases where the change is made by a formula(like `=IF()`,`=VLOOKUP()`) other than auto-change formulas(like `=GOOGLEFINANCE`,`=IMPORTRANGE`,`=IMPORTXML`, etc), Usually a human would need to edit some other cell- In which case, You will be able to capture that event(Which caused a human edit) and make changes to the formula cell instead.
- In cases where the change is done from sheets api, a installed onChange trigger *may* be able to capture the event.