# OnChange not Triggering, Contents change from where Via VLookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have copied and edited a simple script designed to hide show various Rows based on a user input at the top of the sheet, I edited the function onChange as an On Change Trigger.

The Cell C8, has its contents changed via a vLookup, which is i think where the problems arise.

I need the actual end-user input to be a set aesthetic, so I'm using a nicely formatted Input in cell C7, to adjust the contents of C8 which I then hope to Hide/Show Rows.

```
function onChange(e) {     
if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C8') {  
  if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {          
  eval(e.value)();
   }
  }
 }

function HideAll() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideRows(9,189);  // Hide All SW01 Options 
 }

function SG30052MP() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.hideRows(9,189);  // Hide all SW01 to reset
   sheet.showRows(11,15);  // Show SW01 SG300-52MP
    }

function SG30052P() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.hideRows(9,189);  // Hide all SW01 to reset
   sheet.showRows(26,15);  // Show SW01 SG300-52P
    }`
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [e.range.getA1Notation() unable to track changes caused by formula update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828919/e-range-geta1notation-unable-to-track-changes-caused-by-formula-update)

Comment: Why not ``if e..=='C7'{ eval(C8)}``

Comment: Not sure exactly how to add that this is the only way i don't get an error:

      function onChange(e) {     
         if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C7'){ eval(C8)} {  
          if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {          
          eval(e.value)();
          }
           }
             }

Comment: you need to ``getRange('C8').getValue()``, when C7 is edited.

Comment: I think I may have stumbled upon something I a little above my knowledge. I'm gonna get a little more basic and maybe come back to this!

Thankyou for all your help!