# Can't getValues from a named spreadsheet tab, in order to populate a Google Documents

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

So, i tried to setup a script that when you manually fill a GoogleForm it populates a new  Google Doc in a new folder(in the same folder with the active form and spreadsheet). I actually made it, but it was missing some manipulated information from a sheet tab that differs from the form's responses.

PS:(some stuff in code block are in Portuguese language)

```
function substituirPorTags() {
  // IDs dos objetos
  var spreadsheetId = '1aKmVHQNJS60yzbsgScmL*****************';
  var templateDocId = '1rrwmrPk7SLgLsExn0-eEa6vVZM*****************';
  var destinationFolderId = '1vyWFErYN2Z8q9UIXD42a*****************';

  // Abrir o formulário e extrair as respostas (opens form and extract last answers)
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1e6LJ0iW-gbzmyAi0OdQN5W********************/edit');
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var latestResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1];
  var itemResponses = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
  
  var consultor = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var valor = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var fpagamento = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var parcelas = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var vencimentoi = itemResponses[4].getResponse();
  var valori = itemResponses[5].getResponse();
  var nome = itemResponses[6].getResponse();
  var porte = itemResponses[7].getResponse();
  var logradouro = itemResponses[8].getResponse();
  var numero = itemResponses[9].getResponse();
  var bairro = itemResponses[10].getResponse();
  var cidade = itemResponses[11].getResponse();
  var estado = itemResponses[12].getResponse();
  var pais = itemResponses[13].getResponse();
  var cep = itemResponses[14].getResponse();
  var cpfcnpj = itemResponses[15].getResponse();
  var nomeresponsavel = itemResponses[16].getResponse();
  var cpfresponsavel = itemResponses[17].getResponse();
  var nascimentoresponsavel = itemResponses[18].getResponse();
  var telefone = itemResponses[19].getResponse();
  var website = itemResponses[20].getResponse();
  var emailresponsavel = itemResponses[21].getResponse();
  var emailfinanceiro = itemResponses[22].getResponse();
  var titulo = itemResponses[23].getResponse();
  var classe = itemResponses[24].getResponse();
  var nprocesso = itemResponses[25].getResponse();
  var rpi = itemResponses[26].getResponse();
  var classificacao = itemResponses[27].getResponse();
  var deposito = itemResponses[28].getResponse();
  var mnfoposicao = itemResponses[29].getResponse();
  var encaminhamento = itemResponses[30].getResponse();
  var recurso = itemResponses[31].getResponse();
  var deferimento = itemResponses[32].getResponse();
  var mnfpan = itemResponses[33].getResponse();
  var mnfcaducidade = itemResponses[34].getResponse();
  var renovacao = itemResponses[35].getResponse();
  var oposicao = itemResponses[36].getResponse();
  var pan = itemResponses[37].getResponse();
  var caducidade = itemResponses[38].getResponse();
  var transferencia = itemResponses[39].getResponse();
  var nomesedeendereco = itemResponses[40].getResponse();
```

> So far, so good. Here is where it gets ugly

```
// Extrair informações da aba "FINANCEIRO" da planilha *(gets values from sheet tab named FINANCEIRO)*
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var financeiroSheet = ss.getSheetByName('FINANCEIRO');
  var ultimaLinha = financeiroSheet.getLastRow();
  var id = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 1).getValue();
  var valorii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 9).getValue();
  var vencimentoii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 10).getValue();
  var valoriii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 11).getValue();
  var vencimentoiii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 12).getValue();
  var valoriv = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 13).getValue();
  var vencimentoiv = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 14).getValue();
  var valorv = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 15).getValue();
  var vencimentov = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 16).getValue();
  var valorvi = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 17).getValue();
  var vencimentovi = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 18).getValue();
  var valorvii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 19).getValue();
  var vencimentovii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 20).getValue();
  var valorviii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 21).getValue();
  var vencimentoviii = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 22).getValue();
  var valorix = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 23).getValue();
  var vencimentoix = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 24).getValue();
  var valorx = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 25).getValue();
  var vencimentox = financeiroSheet.getRange(ultimaLinha, 26).getValue();
  
  // Abrir o documento modelo (opens doc template)
  var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocId);

  //Abrir a pasta separada (opens destination folder)
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);

  // criar cópia do documento modelo (creates a template copy)
  var copyDoc = templateDoc.makeCopy("CONTRATO_"+ id + nome, destinationFolder);
  
  // Abre a cópia em uma pasta separada (Opens copy)
  var documentofinal = DocumentApp.openById(copyDoc.getId());
  
  // Substituir informações por tags na cópia do documento (replaces document body tags)
  var body = documentofinal.getBody();
  
  // Substituir as tags no documento pelos valores extraídos do formulário e da planilha
  body.replaceText('{{ID}}', id);
  body.replaceText('{{NOME}}', nome);
  body.replaceText('{{CPFCNPJ}}', cpfcnpj);
  body.replaceText('{{PORTE}}', porte);
  body.replaceText('{{ENDEREÇO}}', logradouro);
  body.replaceText('{{NUMERO}}', numero);
  body.replaceText('{{BAIRRO}}', bairro);
  body.replaceText('{{CIDADE}}', cidade);
  body.replaceText('{{UF}}', estado);
  body.replaceText('{{CEP}}', cep);
  body.replaceText('{{SITE}}', website);
  body.replaceText('{{RESPONSAVEL}}', nomeresponsavel);
  body.replaceText('{{CPFRESPONSAVEL}}', cpfresponsavel);
  body.replaceText('{{E-MAIL}}', emailresponsavel);
  body.replaceText('{{TELEFONE}}', telefone);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDDEPO}}', deposito);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDCLASS}}', classificacao);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDEXAM}}', encaminhamento);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDDEFE}}', deferimento);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDMNFOPO}}', mnfoposicao);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDREC}}', recurso);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDMNFPAN}}', mnfpan);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDMNFCAD}}', mnfcaducidade);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDRENO}}', renovacao);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDOPO}}', oposicao);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDPAN}}', pan);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDCAD}}', caducidade);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDTRANSF}}', transferencia);
  body.replaceText('{{QTDATUAL}}', nomesedeendereco);
  body.replaceText('{{VALOR}}', valor);
  body.replaceText('{{TITULO}}', titulo);
  body.replaceText('{{NPROCESSO}}', nprocesso);
  body.replaceText('{{RPI}}', rpi);
  body.replaceText('{{FPAGAMENTO}}', fpagamento);
  body.replaceText('{{PARCELAS}}', parcelas);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOI}}', vencimentoi);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOII}}', vencimentoii);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOIII}}', vencimentoiii);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOIV}}', vencimentoiv);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOV}}', vencimentov);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOVI}}', vencimentovi);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOVII}}', vencimentovii);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOVIII}}', vencimentoviii);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOIX}}', vencimentoix);
  body.replaceText('{{VENCIMENTOX}}', vencimentox);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORI}}', valori);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORII}}', valorii);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORIII}}', valoriii);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORIV}}', valoriv);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORV}}', valorv);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORVI}}', valorvi);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORVII}}', valorvii);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORVIII}}', valorviii);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORIX}}', valorix);
  body.replaceText('{{VALORX}}', valorx);
  body.replaceText('{{CLASSES}}', classe);
  body.replaceText('{{CONSULTOR}}', consultor);

//Save and Close Doc
  documentofinal.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Idk if it is the method I'm using to open the spreadsheet or the .getValue(). Could you guys take a look? I'm really stucked on this.

Forms answers are merging to the final doc and it is being save correctly, but i rly don't know why it doesnt getValues from the named ss.

I have some arrayformulae applied into the named tab headers, could it be returning 1000th row as the lastrow?

Comment: Insert some Logger statements and check the values from the spreadsheet. `id` would be a starter. Anyway, start by comparing the values to the expected outcomes.

Comment: I checked logger using this:  `var lastrowoutput = financeiroSheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("The lastrow value is:" + lastrowoutput)`

And got "The lastrow value is:1000"

So, i'm actually populating the whole sheet with data using array formulae on headers, will try to scavenge some solutions and return with some info.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to really know without an actual sheet and function that produces the problem but here are a few ideas:

getLastRow returns the index of the last row with contents. Spreadsheets are notoriously difficult for quality control. You may not be able to control the last row with contents if you aren't always in control of the sheet. You may need a more consistent method to identify the row that you are really interested in extracting data from.

Google Sheet caches function results using the function parameters as an index to the cache. The same parameter values yield the last known result from the cache. An idea to circumvent the cache is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet). Basically force a parameter with the current timestamp and don't use the parameter.

Thinking about caching, you may also need to call SpreadsheetApp.flush() if there are pending changes to the sheet that haven't been persisted yet.

There's also the chance that your script isn't allowing the formulas to calculate between opening and getting the value. You could assign the formulas to ranges in your script and then grab the values.

```
range.setFormula("=ArrayFormula(...)");
value = range.getValue();
```

Comment: In my working sheet i have installments absolute number (Collumn G), total value (D), first installment payment date (H) and the value of the first installment (F). I created 18 rows, half for amounts  half for dates.

The arrawyformulae works like this:

**To define installment monetary value:** `=ArrayFormula(IFS(G2:G="";"";G2:G<2;"";TRUE;(D2:D-F2:F)/(G2:G-1)))`

**To define installment payment date:** 
`=ArrayFormula(IFS(G2:G="";"";G2:G<2;"";TRUE;DATAM(H2:H;1)))`

The <2 is a condition to match the second installment  and it gets changed when applied to other installment collumns.

Comment: Looks like you aren't alone with this issue. The comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304976/google-script-getvalue-not-working-with-cells-with-a-formula-in-it) might be helpful.