# How to sort 2 different ways from a data validation cell onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an onEdit trigger to sort a list 1 of 2 ways.  The way to sort the list is decided by a data validation.  One sort option (Name Only) would be column 3 Ascending.  The second option (Name and TH) would be sort column 4 descending then column 3 Ascending.

I currently have the following code which triggers if the data validation cell is changed.  This works just fine but doesn't allow me to choose another way to sort the data.

```
function sortRoster() {

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var roster = activeSheet.getRange("B8:D77");
  var sorter = activeSheet.getRange("G4");

  roster.sort( [{ column : 4, ascending: false },{ column : 3, ascending: true }] );
  var clear = activeSheet.getRange("G4").clearContent().setValue("Do you want to Sort?");
}

function onEdit(e) {
  // test if G4 was modified
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet() && e.range.rowStart === 4 && e.range.columnStart === 7) {
    sortRoster(); 

  }
}
```

I have tried first adding another function ( calling it `sortName()` ) which would run the sort on column 3 only.

```
function sortName() {

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var roster = activeSheet.getRange("B8:D77");

  roster.sort( [{ column : 3, ascending: true }] );
  var clear = activeSheet.getRange("G4").clearContent().setValue("Do you want to Sort?");
```

Then I tried changing the if to

```
if (e.source.getActiveSheet() && activeCell == "Name Only") {
  sortName();
  sorter.clearContent().setValue("Choose how to Sort?");
} else if (e.source.getActiveSheet() && activeCell == "Name and TH") {
  sortRoster();
  sorter.clearContent().setValue("Choose how to Sort?");
}
```

This idea does not work and I don't understand why.
I feel I don't fully understand how the event trigger works even after my research online.
I've seen several pages like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828919/e-range-geta1notation-unable-to-track-changes-caused-by-formula-update) that are similar but not that seem to address the same issue I have.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and guidance.

Comment: Doesn't work is not a problem description. Provide [mcve]-logs, your debug efforts, the complete code.

Comment: You need to pass different arguments to `Range#sort` based on the value in the cell that controls sorting.

Comment: I politely disagree @TheMaster .  The code I provided is the only code of the document, therefore the complete code.  The Code at the top is my starting point and the second block of code is the part that is in error (The part that doesn't work).  I have tested this code and otherwise I wouldn't have known it does not work.

The Code is Minimal ( all the code needed to produce the error)
The Code is Complete (all the code of the document)
The Code is Verifiable  [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zjN6e83lwq9zml_O9PH1UBf3SarFhTIMgEx1fjvW53c/edit?usp=sharing) is the document

Comment: @tehhowch what different arguments do you suggest I use?

Comment: Ones that sort the desired range as you desire. TheMaster is correct, "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. There are many possible reasons something may "not work." It may "not work" because of a runtime error. It may "not work" because it doesn't do what you want. It may "not work" because it does *more* than what you want. You must be articulate and specific about your issue and the steps you have taken to resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not complete or verifiable. Where is `activeCell`  and `sortName` declared? Also, what's the error? See View>  Executions and quote the exact error and your efforts in debugging it. I would also argue that it isn't minimal, because you haven't pin pointed the error.

Comment: According to the site you linked above, "Complete-Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem in the question itself" I have provided all the code in the script. All of the above code produces the issue. `sortName` is declared on lines 10-17 & `activeCell` is declared on lines 20 & 23.  The error is that it doesn't sort.  No popup, just nothing happening. My efforts in debugging is trying other various permutations of the script listed above.  According to the site, "Minimal–Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem" I don't know what to cut from the code  above

Comment: `No popup, just nothing happening`. As this is a trigger initiated script, The error, if any will be recorded in the stackdriver. See View>Executions. You'll see whether the script was completed successfully or failed and If failed, the reason for the error.

Comment: on the Executions it says "ReferenceError: "activeCell" is not defined. at onEdit(Sort Roster:12)"  I don't understand.  how do you define the active cell if the active cell could be where ever you click?

Comment: Review "event objects" in the documentation.  You might be looking for `e.value`. There is no global `activeCell`: This isn't vba. [Edit] your question to quote the error. Finding the error is the first step in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sorting onEdit() via a couple of Checkboxes

This needs a couple of checkboxes in A4 and A5.  It's a part something else. You also need to create an installable onEdit trigger for onCheckOpenSideBar(e) or your can use the function provided.

```
function onCheckOpenSideBar(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet1')return;
  if(e.range.rowStart==4 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      sortByCol(3);
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==5 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      sortByCol(4,5);
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
}

function sortByCol(col,col2) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,3,getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss),3);
  if(col2) {
    rg.sort([{column: col,ascending:true},{column: col2,ascending:true}]);
  }else{
    rg.sort({column: col, ascending:true});
  }
}

function createOnEditTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onCheckOpenSideBar').forSpreadsheet('Spreadsheet ID').onEdit().create();
}
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like before sorting.

[image]

The checkboxes in A2 and A3 were used for opening a sidebar and a dialog.

## Adding the use of a Validation DropDown

```
function onCheckOpenSideBar(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet1')return;
  if(e.range.rowStart==2 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      openTheSidebar();
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==3 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      openTheDialog();
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==4 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      sortByCol(3);
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==5 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      sortByCol(4,5);
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==6 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='C') {
      sortByCol(3);
    }
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==6 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='D,E') {
      sortByCol(4,5);
    }
  }
}
```

Now it Looks Like this:

[image]

Or This:

[image]

Data Validation Dialog:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply but this does not help my situation.  I need to this to be on a data validation.  (Lack of room for a check box and it's description)

Comment: @EureekaHavoc I added a Validation DropDown.