# Timestamp in google sheet when specific cell is updated by vlookup

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

i want to update specific cell in google sheet with time stamp when other cell is updated by vlookup function from some other sheet.

my code is working fine if i manually edit the cell but if cell is updated by some vlookup then not getting the timestamp.

```
function onEdit(event)
{
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+3";
  //var timestamp_format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var timestamp_format = "hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "AFT 2:45";
  var timeStampColName = "BTST Brkout Time";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('SCAN'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Actual result:
if i update any cell in column "AFT 2:45" then timestamp is coming automatically in column "BTST Brkout Time" which is correct.

If value in any cell in column "AFT 2:45" is updated by vlookup function then timestamp is not updated in column "BTST brkout Time".

Expected Result:
If value in any cell in column "AFT 2:45" is updated by vlookup function then timestamp should be updated in column "BTST brkout Time".

Comment: This is normal behavior. Only user edits fire triggers. If you need to constantly monitor the state of your sheet, use a time-based trigger to compare the current state to a previous state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [e.range.getA1Notation() unable to track changes caused by formula update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828919/e-range-geta1notation-unable-to-track-changes-caused-by-formula-update)