# How do I restrict a trigger to a specific sheet/tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have written a script in google sheets that will change the time stamp in the selected cell anytime the entire spreadsheet is updated at all. However, I need the timestamp to only update when one single sheet(tab) is updated. Here is my current function:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Board")
    .getRange('A28')
    .setValue(new Date());
}
```

The name of the sheet(tab) that I want to check for an update in is "Input" and the specific cell in the tab is A1 if that matters.

Comment: Hi Clay, I posted my answer. I hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Looks like that does the trick, Thanks Marios!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for :

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if ( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Input" && (row==1 && col==1) ){
 e.source.getSheetByName('Board').getRange('A28').setValue(new Date())      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onEdit` trigger triggers whenever any sheet/tab is edited. It cannot be restricted to a single sheet.  However, even if it is triggered, it is possible to make it do nothing with a simple [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and testing the [`event object`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that is sent on each edit, which contains the circumstances of the edit made.

**Sample**:

```js
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} param1
 */
function onEdit({ range: /*edited range*/ eRange }) {
  const restrictCell = 'A1',
    restrictToSheet = 'Input';
  if (
    eRange.getA1Notation() !== restrictCell ||
    eRange.getSheet().getName() !== restrictToSheet
  )
    return;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Board')
    .getRange('A28')
    .setValue(new Date());
}
```