# Google Script Erasing Formula on Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell (A1) that updates automatically and I would like to use the next cell (B1) to return the max value seen by cell A1. I know nothing about scripts so I google it and found the following script that works but only if A1 doesn't have a formula in it (manually enter a number in the cell but I don't want that). Is there a way to make this work?

```
function recordMax() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B1");
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  range.setValues([[values[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828919/e-range-geta1notation-unable-to-track-changes-caused-by-formula-update

Answer (score 1):

Instead of of changing the values of `A1:B1` just change the value of `B1`.

```
function recordMax() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B1");
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(Math.max(values[0], values[1]));
}
```